# Nvidia graphics is activated but seems not to be used

Tags: nvidia

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have activate nvidia card but it is still not used.

This command to know wich card is used :

```
lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"
```

this is the output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"
```

This is NOT the command to see which adapter is used. This command lists PCI bus and filters it by keywords. `lspci` just shows all PCI devices no matter if they are used or not.

If you run it another way:

```
lspci | grep -E 'VGA|3D'
```

you will see both adapters.

If you really want to see which one is used, run

```
prime-select query
```

or

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

But your GUI program shows it quite well too.